# Disable front end editing in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0

How do you disable front-end editing in joomla 3.6.5? I need to be able to give people a sneak peek sometimes when a site is offline because it's in development, but don't want them to accidentally edit my articles in front end. 
I have turned everything to 'hide' option in my admin login. I went to front end and still see 'edit' option in modules.

I really hope that by now Joomla has a way to accomplish this without hacking, but if it's the only way then so be it. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check this article for module editing. https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/frontend-module-editing
let me know if this does not solve.

Answer (score 0):

Other people can only edit articles if they have the appropriate autorisations (Author, Editor, Publisher, Super User).
When you're logged in as a Super User you will see an option to edit the article. This does not mean, that a 'Registered' user sees this option.
If they do see the edit-option, they probably have the wrong autorisation. Then you might consider changing this.